# Viewing a protein or bio structure in Chembio3D in its natural conformation

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, computational-chemistry, software

I notice when using SMILES or a IUPAC name for many molecules and generating them in Chembio3D, and then running MM2 > Minimize Energy, the structures produced are most of the time not reflections of any conformation observed physiologically.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can import protein and other macromolecules into Chembio3D, perhaps from a database somewhere, where I can view their precise arrangement either as found in crystallography or in vivo in their usual forms at physiological pH. Most importantly, the proteins would need to be accurate (something I find lacking when generating structures by name in chemdraw/chembio3d).

I appreciate that the proteins and other molecules are always changing conformation and interacting with other molecules, but at least a reasonable prediction of some realistic conformations to view them in 3D would be nice, instead of conformations that might rarely/never exist in a cell. Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about this? What would be the specific steps I need to follow to import these proteins into Chembio3D?

Comment: A side question, can you alter bond angles in ChemBio3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are looking for is the [Protein Data Bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank).

You can get to it with one of these links.
www.wwpdb.org
www.pdbe.org
www.rcsb.org/pdb
www.pdbj.org

Comment: Short and to the point. :) Might be better to link to the actual page, http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do and not the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak There are 3 links on the Wikipedia page, depending on the organization that accesses the information.